# C forks and processes, ¿Why its necessary this?

Tags: c, process, signals, child-process

I am studying C and I have been trying to make a simple test program. The problem is that I have a problem that is solved by a way that I dont understand. This is My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void trat1(int s){
    signal(SIGALRM, trat1);
}
void trat2(int s){
    signal(SIGALRM, trat2);
}

int main( void ) {
    int statusHijo1, statusHijo2;
    int hijo1, hijo2;
    int hijoFinalizado, status;
    statusHijo1 =0;
    statusHijo2 = 0;

    if((hijo1 = fork()) == 0){
        /* Hijo 1 */

        printf("-- Hijo1 PID:%d | Parent PID:%d", getpid(), getppid());
        printf("\n -- Hijo1 Lanzando SIGTERM -- \n");
        while(1){
            signal(SIGALRM, trat2);
            alarm(1);
            pause();
            printf("  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. \n");
        }
    } 
    else{
        if ( (hijo2=fork()) == 0 ) { 
            /* Hijo 2 */

                printf("++ Hijo2 PID:%d | Parent PID:%d \n", getpid(), getppid());
                signal(SIGALRM, trat2);
                alarm(5);
                pause();
                kill(hijo1, SIGKILL); 
                printf("++ Hijo2 Sending Kill signal to Hijo1\n");
                printf("++ Proceso Hijo2 terminado\n");
        } 
        else{
            /* Padre */

            do{
                hijoFinalizado = wait(&status); //El hijo finalizado es el que cambia el estado del programa
                if(hijoFinalizado == hijo1) statusHijo1 = 1;
                else if(hijoFinalizado == hijo2) statusHijo2 = 1;

            }while(!statusHijo1 || !statusHijo2);
            printf("\n** Soy el padre con PID: %d y he terminado \n", getpid());

        }   
    }

}
```

This program is very simple, The father is waitting for his two childs, 1 will be waitting for 5 seconds until the second one kills it.

Here the output from console:

```
-- Hijo1 PID:29793 | Parent PID:29792
 -- Hijo1 Lanzando SIGTERM -- 
++ Hijo2 PID:29794 | Parent PID:29792 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
++ Hijo2 Sending Kill signal to Hijo1
++ Proceso Hijo2 terminado

** Soy el padre con PID: 29792 y he terminado
```

The problem is that I dont know how  `hijoFinalizado = wait(&status);` works, becouse without it the program doesnt funct.
This is what occurs without it:

```
-- Hijo1 PID:1547 | Parent PID:1546
 -- Hijo1 Lanzando SIGTERM -- 
++ Hijo2 PID:1548 | Parent PID:1546 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
++ Hijo2 Sending Kill signal to Hijo1
++ Proceso Hijo2 terminado
```

And gets stuck here.

¿Why a variable that I dont declare is the one who decides if a process has finished?

¿Why doing `while( (wait(&statusHijo1)!=hijo1)&& (wait(&statusHijo2)!=hijo2) ) ;` instead isnnt correct?
This is what occurs doing this:

```
-- Hijo1 PID:1148 | Parent PID:1147
++ Hijo2 PID:1149 | Parent PID:1147 
 -- Hijo1 Lanzando SIGTERM -- 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
  -- Hijo1 awaitting 1 sec.. 
++ Hijo2 Sending Kill signal to Hijo1
++ Proceso Hijo2 terminado
```

And gets stuck here.

**[Addition]**

¿What is the real function of trat1 and trat2? I know that they are important but I dont know why.

Sorry for my English, and thanks very much.

Comment: `wait()` waits for any process and the return value tells you which process changed its state or if an error occurred. To wait for a specific child only you can use `waitpid`, but even with different expected run time you cannot be  absolutely sure which process terminates first, so waiting for any of the child processes is the right way to implement this. What exactly means "without it the program **doesnt funct**"? What happens or doesn't happen? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, don't answer in comments.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks very much for your explanation, it helps me so much. I have update my question an added another question.

Comment: Please show how (the relevant part of) the source code looks like in the version without the `wait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why a variable that I dont declare is the one who decides if a process has finished?*

You mean `status`? You do *declare* it; you simply don't *initialize* it. And that's fine, because `wait` doesn't read it; `wait` populates it. In other words, it's not an input; it's an output.

`wait` waits for a child to finish. It returns the PID of the process, and it sets `status` to the child's exit status.

You can use the status as follows:

```
if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
   printf("Child killed by signal %d\.n", WSTOPSIG(status));
}
else if (WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
   printf("Child exited with error %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
else {
   printf("Child completed successfully.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

Comment: So wait is the one who initializes the variable status, and inserts the child pid into status,  ¿No?

Comment: @Ibai `wait` doesn't insert the child PID into `status`. If a child has changed its state, `wait` will write the status into the variable and use the PID as return value. A positive return value is always a PID.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to additional questions only**

The implementation

```
while( (wait(&statusHijo1)!=hijo1)&& (wait(&statusHijo2)!=hijo2) ) ;
```

is wrong because you cannot `wait` for a specific child only. (You need `waitpid` for this purpose, but you must make sure in your code that the specified child is able to terminate.)

You can walk through the code and think about what will happen.

Examples:

Assuming child 1 terminates before child 2.

The first `wait(&statusHijo1)` will save the state of child 1 to `statusHijo1`, return the PID of child 1 and the condition `!=hijo1` will be false.

As the result of the logical AND, so it will not call the second `wait(&statusHijo2)` and terminate the loop. Your program will not wait for child 2, and `statusHijo2` will be unchanged.

Assuming child 2 terminates before child 1.

The first `wait(&statusHijo1)` will save the state of child 2 to `statusHijo1`, return the PID of child 2 and the condition `!=hijo1` will be true, so it will call the second `wait(&statusHijo2)`.

This will save the state of child 1 to `statusHijo2`, return the PID of child 1 and the condition `!=hijo2` will be true. 
The loop will repeat because both conditions are true.

It will call `wait(&statusHijo1)` again, which  will return -1 because you have no child to wait for. The condition `!=hijo1` will be true, it will call `wait(&statusHijo2)`, return -1 and the condition `!=hijo2` will be true, so it will repeat the loop again.

You will get an endless loop in this case.

---

`trat1` and `trat2` are signal handler functions for `SIGALRM`. They do nothing more than re-establish themselves. The implementation of `signal()` varies between different UNIX systems. On some systems, reception of a signal will reset the signal handler to the default, so the signal handler has to call `signal()` again.

Without a signal handler, a signal `SIGALRM` would terminate the process.

Instead of `signal(SIGALRM, trat2); alarm(5); pause();` you could also use `sleep(5);`.